# Why does browser "Firefox Page Source" show two closing </body> tags?

Tags: html, dreamweaver-templates

Dreamweaver showing error message
"unbalanced body tag"

Something causing closing body tag twice.  and

Need to fix so only one  at end.

Comment: Fixed previous problem that was causing double closing body tag, </body> </body> Caused by Business Catalyst not liking Dreamweaver template EditRegion tag. <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="EditRegion4" -->EditRegion4<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->  Switched back to: {tag_pagecontent} corrected trouble. Now have correct body closing. </body>

Answer (score 1):

Code at the beginning of the document:

```
<body>
<div class="body">
```

Code at the end:

```
</body>
</body>
```

The opening `div` with a class of `body` is never closed - the first instance of `</body>` should be changed to `</div>`.

Comment: Fixed problem with double closing body tag, </body> </body>